# Can $f_x$ be undefined while $f_y$ is defined?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

While studying the critical points of two variable functions, I noticed that my textbook mentioned that if one partial derivative is undefined at a point, then that point is a critical point. I was wondering if it possible for one partial derivative to exist and another to not exist?

Comment: $f(x,y) =  1_\mathbb{Q}(x) y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the partial derivatives of the function 
$$f(x,y)=|x|$$
at the point $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, let  $f(x,y) = \sqrt[3]{x} y$, then at $(0,0)$ $f_x$ is not defined while $f_y$ is.